# How to use $? and test to check function?

Tags: bash, shell, exit, error-handling

```
    #!/bin/sh

function checkExit(){
    if test "$?" != "0"; then
      echo Command $1 exited with abnormal status
      exit 1;
    else echo $?
    fi
}

function echoThenRun () { # echo and then run the command
  echo $1
  $1
  ret=$?
  echo $ret
  return $ret
}
file=test_file
echo > $file
echoThenRun "test -f $file"
checkExit $file
echo "all right!"
```

The output of executing the script:

```
$  ~/Downloads/test.sh 
test -f test_file
0
1 # why 1 here??
all right!
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a simpler way of what you're doing. If you use `set -x` (or `set -o xtrace` - same thing), the script will automatically echo each line before it's executed.

Also, as soon as you execute another command, `$?` is replaced with the exit code of that command.

You'll have to back it up to a variable if you're going to be doing anything with it other than a quick test-and-forget. The `[` is actually a program that has its own exit code.

### Using `set +x` to echo commands

For example:

```bash
(
    set -x # Cause commands to echo, but ONLY inside of this (...)
    execute some command...
    # Any further commands in these parens will also echo.
)
# Command echoing will be OFF at this point because we're outside of the (...).
# Now, $? holds the exit code of the (...) which gets it from the
# exit code of the last command executed inside of it.
result=$?
if [ "$result" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Your command exited with non-zero status $result"
fi
```

This will print on stderr:

```
+ execute some command...
```

### Alternate method with `set +x`

You can also use `set +x` to disable command echoing afterwards:

```bash
set -x # Cause commands to echo
execute some command...
result=$?
set +x # Turn off command echoing
```

However this approach is less clean, ultimately printing on stderr:

```
+ execute some command...
+ result=127
+ set +x
```

Comment: the `if` statement is what i was looking for

Comment: omg why nobody told me earlier that `set -x` exists!!! That's the most useful feature ever. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do we need `set +x`?

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like the command `test "$?" != "0"` ends up setting `$?` to `1`.

The value `$?` gets used in the arguments to `test`. `test` sets `$?` to a non-zero value because `"0"` is lexically equal to `"0"`. The `"!="` makes `test` return non-zero.